# How to get films that were rented on Thursday

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to get the First names Last names of customers and the films that were rented on Thursday but what I put in is gives me an Empty set.

**This is where I am getting table info from**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html

---

```
 select first_name, last_name, title 
 from sakila_customer join sakila_rental using(customer_id)
 join   sakila_inventory using(inventory_id) join sakila_film using(film_id)
 where sakila_rental.rental_date =  DAYNAME('Thursday');
```

Comment: Are any of these columns nullable? Perhaps consider using a left join rather than an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the function in the wrong way:

```
where dayname(sakila_rental.rental_date) = 'Thursday'
```

Your query would also be easier to write and read if you used table aliases:

```
 select c.first_name, c.last_name, f.title 
 from sakila_customer c join
      sakila_rental r
      using (customer_id) join 
      sakila_inventory i
      using (inventory_id) join
      sakila_film f
      using (film_id)
 where dayname(r.rental_date) = 'Thursday';
```

If you are learning SQL< then now is a good time to start good habits such as using table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I think `sakila_rental.rental_date =  DAYNAME('Thursday');` should be `DAYNAME(sakila_rental.rental_date) =  'Thursday';`. After all, `Thursday` is already a day name, and you want to compare it to the day name of the date.